# WARNING: Unable to pull data from 'http://gems.github.com': bad response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz)

Tags: github

I tried install rails 6.0.0 using command

```
gem install rails --pre
```

output:
....

> WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'http://gems.github.com': bad
>   response Not Found 404 (http://gems.github.io/specs.4.8.gz) 40 gems
>   installed

System Configuration:

Mac OSX 10.13.6

ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin17]

OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

Since this is the test configuration with rails 6 beta, I like to clear all system warning in order to focus in rails. 
Is there any solution to clear the warning?

Comment: Why `gems.github.io`? https://github.com/gems seems not related to Ruby. Maybe some configuration file error? A valid URL maybe https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz.

Comment: That code from 'gem install rails --pre' I wish I can tried replace that code myself.

Comment: Also, that error references two different but similar domains: one `.io` and one `.com`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Chris No, not a typo. It's was copy from error message. Also there are report of same error in different cause as well. But solution not apply to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did.
Go to my github account and add new gpg (after [created new one](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key))
Then no more warning!